# Change image visibility on timer.elapsed event

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, visibility

I have this code which makes my image visible and starts timer:

```
image1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000) { AutoReset=false};
timer.Enabled = IsEnabled;
timer.Start();
timer.Elapsed += hideImage;
```

This is event which fires after 2 seconds:

```
private void hideImage(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

MessageBox.Show works and message box is displayed. The problem is that image stays visible. Any ideas how to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: You closed the MessageBox, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I closed the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void hideImage(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden));
}
```

Not sure how this din't crash for you in the first place cos your Thread is probably not the Main UI thread and that's probably what's blocking the updates too.

Answer (score 0):

Add to hideImage `Refresh` call  of the control that holds the image.